# Conforming to protocols - Bug?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two protocols and views that conform to them. One view compiles and the other does not. Could this be a bug or has the syntax changed?

I also get this error on top of "does not conform to protocol of the 2nd error" Could this be related?

[image]

Protocols

```
protocol RecipeComponent: CustomStringConvertible {
    init()
}

protocol ModifyComponentView: View {
    associatedtype Component
    init(component: Binding<Component>, creationAction: @escaping (Component) -> Void)
    
}
```

The first view compiles and conforms..

```
import SwiftUI

struct ModifyIngredientView: ModifyComponentView {
    
    @Binding var ingredient: Ingredient
    let createAction: ((Ingredient) -> Void)
    
    //@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    init(component: Binding<Ingredient>, creationAction: @escaping (Ingredient) -> Void) {
        self._ingredient = component
        self.createAction = creationAction
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        

        VStack{
            Form{
                TextField("Ingredient", text: $ingredient.name)
                Stepper(value: $ingredient.quantity, in: 1...100, step: 0.5) {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Quantity:")
                        TextField("Quantity", value: $ingredient.quantity, formatter: NumberFormatter.decimal)
                            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    }
                }
                Picker(selection: $ingredient.unit) {
                    ForEach(Ingredient.Unit.allCases, id: \.self) {unit in
                        Text(unit.rawValue)
                    }
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Unit")
                        Spacer()
                        //Text(ingredient.unit.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Save") {
                        createAction(ingredient)
                        //dismiss()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                

                }
        
            }
        }
    }

extension NumberFormatter {
    static var decimal: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }
}

struct ModifyIngredientView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    @State static var emptyIngredient = Ingredient()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ModifyIngredientView(component: $emptyIngredient) { ingredient in
                print(ingredient)
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Add Ingredient")
    }
}
```

The 2nd does not........

```
import SwiftUI

struct ModifyDirectionView: ModifyComponentView {
    
    @Binding var direction: Direction
    let createAction: ((Direction) -> Void)
    
    init(component: Binding<Direction>, createAction: @escaping (Direction) -> Void) {
        self._direction = component
        self.createAction = createAction
    }

    private let listBackgroundColor = AppColor.background
    private let listTextColor = AppColor.foreground

    //@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var mode
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Direction Description", text: $direction.description)
                .listRowBackground(listBackgroundColor)
            Toggle("Optional", isOn: $direction.isOptional)
                .listRowBackground(listBackgroundColor)
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Save") {
                    createAction(direction)
                    //mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                Spacer()
            }.listRowBackground(listBackgroundColor)
        }
        .foregroundColor(listTextColor)
    }
}

struct ModifyDirectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var recipe = Recipe.testRecipes[0]

    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ModifyDirectionView(component: $recipe.directions[0]) { direction in
                print(direction)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the parameter name of the init of the second view from `createAction` to `creationAction`, as it is declared in the protocol

Comment: I might just quit programming

Comment: :D It happens, you just need some rest